# Hive UDF return expected result but also added null and newline in result

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, hue, hive-udf

I have written Hive UDF in Java for decoding the information, for that we used the below code.

```
public Text evaluate(Text str) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = (SALT + KEY).getBytes("UTF8");
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        keyBytes = messageDigest.digest(keyBytes);
        keyBytes = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, 16);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        String decryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes()));
        return new Text(decryptedString);
    }
```

The below query is executed successfully with UDF.

[image: Hive Query to check UDF is working]

below is the Gender table where I'm executing the UDF

[image: Whole Gender table]

When I execute the query on the gender table with UDF, I'm getting the null and new line in it. Please find the below screenshot with highlighted areas.
[image: Query with UDF]

I'm expecting the result in one line only. Please help and let me know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Try to replace `Text` with `String`. Also, what happens if you run the following query `select ToDeidentId(gender) from demo.gender`?

Comment: Can you try to do same in Hive console, not Hue UI? To make sure it's not a bug from Hue's side

Comment: @serge_k `select ToDeidentId(gender) from demo.gender` show the same result with newline

Comment: @GoodDok I tried the Hive console as well result is the same (Extra column and new line)

Comment: How about replacing return type `Text` to `String` and returning just `decryptedString`? does it help?

Comment: When I changed the execution engine to Spark: set hive.execution.engine=spark; then the above query ran successfully.

Does anyone know the reason of this behavior?